# ArrayList Integer Sorting with Strings attached

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, int

I am trying to sort integers that are in an ArrayList, that part is working but I am also trying to keep a parallel array matched with the correct integer. I can't make them into a grouped object either. So if I had 3 words with 3 numbers (Numbers in an ArrayList and words in an ArrayList ("Hello" - 2, "The" - 5, "For" - 1). I would want For and 1 to come first, then Hello and to last would be The and 5. So It would carry over the word with the number. the code I have below is sorting Integers correctly but it seems that the words are being randomized.

```
void quickSort2 (ArrayList<Integer> list, int first, int last, ArrayList list2){

    //Set first and last
    int g = first, h = last;
    int midIndex, dividingValue;

    //middle values
    midIndex = (first + last) / 2;
    dividingValue = list.get(midIndex);

    System.out.println("midIdex = "+midIndex + "first = "+first+"last = "+last);

    //find if higher or lower
    do{
        while (list.get(g) < dividingValue) {
            g++;

        }
        while (list.get(h) > dividingValue){
            h--;

        }
        if (g <= h){  

            //Switch ints (Works)
            int temp = list.get(g);
            list.set(g,list.get(h));
            list.set(h,temp);
            g++;
            h--;

            //Switch Strings with the ints (Doesnt work)
            ArrayList blah = new ArrayList();

            blah.add(list2.get(g));
            list2.set(g,list2.get(h));
            list2.set(h,blah.get(0));

        }
    }
    while (g<h);

    //Back to the method
    if(h>first) {
        quickSort2(list, first, h, list2);

    }
    if(g<last) {
        quickSort2(list, g, last, list2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a sorted map implementation.

Comment: "I can't make them into a grouped object either" why? how about a key-value pair?

Comment: By a "grouped object", I assume you mean some object that has both the integer and the `String`.  So why can't you make a grouped object?  That's the normal way of sorting items with multiple pieces of data when you just want to sort on one of those pieces as the key.

Comment: Im just learning java and this is for a class. I would be allowed to do that but i don't know how to. If someone could explain, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try switching the Strings before you increment the values of g and h... Also you don't need to create the Arraylist blah - just get the string like you do for the int

Something like this... I haven't looked to deeply into your code but this is most likely an error...

```
//Switch ints (Works)
int temp = list.get(g);
list.set(g,list.get(h));
list.set(h,temp);
// *** Don't increment here ***

// *** Switch Strings with the ints first ***
String tempStr = list2.get(g);
list2.set(g,list2.get(h));
list2.set(h,tempStr );

// *** Now increment ***
 g++;
 h--;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I always thought once you were in an if, you stayed in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple class to group an integer key and `String` together:

```
public class DataItem {
    // These are the pieces of data each DataItem will carry around
    private int key;
    private String data;

    // This is a constructor; if you say new DataItem(2,"Hello"), it creates an
    // object whose key is 2 and data is "Hello"
    public DataItem(int key, String data) {
        this.key = key;
        this.data = data;
    }

    // A method to get the object's key
    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    // A method to get the object's data
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

Now your `quickSort2` method will take an `ArrayList<DataItem>` instead of an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  When you use the `get` method on the `ArrayList`, it will return an entire `DataItem` instead of just an `Integer`.  That means that if you want the integer, you'll need to call `getKey()` to get it.  So instead of

```
dividingValue = list.get(midIndex);
```

you'd say

```
dividingValue = list.get(midIndex).getKey();
```

and instead of

```
    while (list.get(g) < dividingValue) {
```

it would be

```
    while (list.get(g).getKey() < dividingValue) {
```

The good news, though, is that when you switch the items, it will switch the entire `DataItem`, which means the `String` will stay with the integer, which is what you want.  So under your "Switch ints" comment, change the type of `temp` from `int` to `DataItem`.  Then your swap will swap everything.

(To make this even better, you can have `DataItem` implement `Comparable<DataItem>`, by adding a `compareTo` method that will compare one `DataItem` to another by comparing just the `key` fields.  Then you can use built-in sort and other methods on arrays of `DataItem`.  I'll let you read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) yourself.)